# nested forEach() function change all childrens of parents Element at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hover over bigger blocks (the blue ones) all the small block change to black at once.

I want only to change the color of the small block inside the hovered blue block not all of them.

Also, I know with CSS (pseudo-selector, `:hover`) can do the same but I want to do it with JS as I said this is not my main code.

```js
const smallContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".small-container")
const logoContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".logo-container")

smallContainer.forEach((value) => {
  value.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    logoContainer.forEach((valuein) => {
      valuein.classList.remove("logo-container")
      valuein.classList.add("logo-container-animation")
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.small-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.logo-container-animation {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
  <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
  <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
  <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: event delegation -> target will help you here

Answer (score 0):

**Prev:** Use the index of the hovered element.
**Prev Update:** I've added an extra snippet in order if you wanted to remove the effect after the mouse leave.
**Updated:** For selecting whatever red boxes are in the blue box, use `querySelectorAll` and do an iteration.
**Roko C. Buljan**'s comment: Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`. [Reason](https://thisthat.dev/mouseenter-vs-mouseover/)

```js
const smallContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".small-container")
const logoContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".logo-container")

smallContainer.forEach((value, i) => {
  const logoContainers = value.querySelectorAll(".logo-container")

  value.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    /* Prev
      logoContainer[i].classList.remove("logo-container");
      logoContainer.classList.add("logo-container-animation")
    */
    // <!-------- UPDATED:  --------!>
    logoContainers.forEach(elm => {
      elm.classList.remove("logo-container")
      elm.classList.add("logo-container-animation")
    })
    // <!-------- UPDATED:  --------!>
  })
  // <!-------- EXTRA:  --------!> 
  value.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    /* Prev
      logoContainer[i].classList.add("logo-container");
      logoContainer.classList.remove("logo-container-animation")
    */
    // <!-------- UPDATED:  --------!>
    logoContainers.forEach(elm => {
      elm.classList.add("logo-container")
      elm.classList.remove("logo-container-animation")
    })
    // <!-------- UPDATED:  --------!>
  })
})
```

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.small-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  transition: all 2s;
}

.logo-container-animation {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="small-container">
    <span class="logo-container"></span>
    <span class="logo-container"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="small-container">
    <span class="logo-container"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="small-container">
    <span class="logo-container"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="small-container">
    <span class="logo-container"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if we have 2 logo-container in same block

Comment: Good question. I updated the question for you.

Comment: Do you know the difference b/w `mouseenter` and `mouseover`? mouseleave and mouseout? and when to use which?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You can ask a question about this and I'll answer it.

Comment: Sorry for not being more suggestive with my comment. What I meant is: `mouseenter` should be used instead of `mouseover`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer if you have 2 block

```js
const smallContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".small-container")
const logoContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".logo-container")

smallContainer.forEach((value, index) => {
value.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
logoContainer.forEach((valuein, indexin) => {
if (indexin == 0) {
logoContainer[index * 2].classList.remove("logo-container")
logoContainer[index * 2].classList.add("logo-container-animation")

}
else {
logoContainer[index * 2 + 1].classList.remove("logo-container")
logoContainer[index * 2 + 1].classList.add("logo-container-animation")

}
})

})
})
smallContainer.forEach((value, index) => {
value.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
logoContainer.forEach((valuein, indexin) => {
if (indexin == 0) {
logoContainer[index * 2].classList.remove("logo-container-animation")
logoContainer[index * 2].classList.add("logo-container")

}
else {
logoContainer[index * 2 + 1].classList.remove("logo-container-animation")
logoContainer[index * 2 + 1].classList.add("logo-container")

}
})

})
})
```

```css
.main-container {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.small-container {
 height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: blue;
transition: all .5s;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.logo-container {
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
transition: all .5s;
}

.logo-container-animation {
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<heard>
</heard>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
        <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
        <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
        <div class="small-container"><span class="logo-container"></span><span class="logo-container"></span></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Amini the update is just like my first code, but because of your help, I find the answer tnx check . its work